# Unable to determine Cesium base URL automatically (Typescript)

Tags: typescript, webpack, cesiumjs

I am trying to setup cesium and resium for react typescript and got stuck on the very initial steps. I am currently referencing steps from the following [resium website](https://resium.darwineducation.com/installation), from here I have installed the packages and attempted to setup webpack based on the following [steps](https://resium.darwineducation.com/installation1). Based on the steps i installed the following package

- npm install copy-webpack-plugin html-webpack-plugin html-webpack-include-assets-plugin
- npm install cesium resium

The following [example](https://github.com/darwin-education/resium/tree/master/example) was also presented so i attempted to mimic the settings as much as possible creating and tweaking the following files in my root directory

- webpack.config.js
- package.json (Adding of scripts)

Once done I changed the following setting `CESIUM_BASE_URL: JSON.stringify("/cesium")` in `webpack.config.js` to point to my python server(`https://localhost:5000`) for the necessary tiles.

With this I expected the error to at least go away or maybe even stating another error such as "Asset XXX not found". But the error stating `DeveloperError: Unable to determine Cesium base URL automatically, try defining a global variable called CESIUM_BASE_URL` still persists.

I have also tried setting a variable for `CESIUM_BASE_URL` in `env.local` but it still doesn't work. Any pointers or guidance to any missing steps will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this script before others (or just before cesium) to your index.html

```
    ...
    </body>
    <script>
      window.CESIUM_BASE_URL = 'https://localhost:5000/';
    <script>
    <script>
    ...
```

Resources:
https://cesium.com/blog/2016/01/26/cesium-and-webpack/#ive-already-got-webpack-set-up-just-tell-me-how-to-use-cesium
https://github.com/opensensorhub/osh-js/issues/55

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is probably in your `webpack.config.js` file by adding the `CopyPlugin` from webpack.

In the config:

```
      new DefinePlugin({
        CESIUM_BASE_URL: JSON.stringify(env.CESIUM_BASE_URL || 'http://localhost/'),
      }),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
configureWebpack: {
     plugins: [
      new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [
          { from: Path.resolve('./node_modules/cesium/Source/Workers'), to: 'Workers' },
          { from: Path.resolve('./node_modules/cesium/Source/Assets'), to: 'Assets' },
          { from: Path.resolve('./node_modules/cesium/Source/Widgets'), to: 'Widgets' },
          { from: Path.resolve('./node_modules/cesium/Source/ThirdParty/Workers'), to: 'WoThirdParty/Workersrkers' },
        ]
      }),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      CESIUM_BASE_URL: JSON.stringify('./')
      })
      ],
  },
```