# Cesium using local/offline tileserver (TypeScript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, cesiumjs

I am trying to set up a local/offline tileserver to serve Cesium's tiles for the 3D Planet/Globe. I have completed my setup for Resium and Cesium based on the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58990689/unable-to-determine-cesium-base-url-automatically-typescript) I created. After the necessary setup I then retrieved a [Precompiled Cesium Assets](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/tree/master/Source) provided by cesium and placed it within my Python Server. I Have also came across the following guide for [Offline Cesium](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/wiki/Offline-Guide) as well as an example for [Online Cesium](https://resium.darwineducation.com/examples/?path=/story/viewer--basic).

After following the guide I noticed that it wasn't working as expected and found out that [createTileMapServiceImageryProvider](https://cesium.com/docs/cesiumjs-ref-doc/createTileMapServiceImageryProvider.html) has been deprecated, so I decided to use [UrlTemplateImageryProvider](https://cesium.com/docs/cesiumjs-ref-doc/UrlTemplateImageryProvider.html) instead.

Next, I began to render react cesium using the following code.

First, I did the necessary Imports

```
import * as cesium from 'cesium';
import * as React from 'react';
import { Entity, PointGraphics, Viewer } from 'resium';
```

Secondly, I created my Tile Server Properties

```
const tms = new cesium.UrlTemplateImageryProvider({
   url: 'https://localhost:5000/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
   maximumLevel:10,
})
```

Once created I used it for my Viewer.

```
<Viewer
   baseLayerPicker={ false }
   geocoder={ false }
   imageryProvider={ tms }
   full={ false }
   homeButton={ false }
   fullscreenButton={ false }
   vrButton={ false }
   infoBox={ false }
   navigationHelpButton={ false }
>
   <Entity position= { cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegree(-74, 40, 100) }>
      <PointGraphics pixelSize={ 10 }/>
   </Entity>
</Viewer>
```

Even with the following settings above I noticed that my "Network" tab is not retrieving the necessary PNG Files. Which means that cesium is not even attempting to render my Planet/Globe for some reason.

Currently, there are two errors within my console which states `importScripts failed for Workers/createVerticesFromHeightmap.....` and `TypeError: data.loaderConfig is undefined`

It can be noted that `geocoder` and `baseLayerPicker` is set as false to prevent an error related to `cesium ion default access token`.

Comment: createTileMapServiceProvider has been deprecated in favor of TileMapServiceImageryProvider. Trying using that instead: https://cesium.com/docs/cesiumjs-ref-doc/TileMapServiceImageryProvider.html?classFilter=TileMap